# Scala Akka Flow output dealing with an Either

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I am facing a problem using akka http and web socket.
I have a function through my code that is returning me the following type:

```
Flow[String, Either[RuntimeException, T], Any]
```

And from that type I have to exit with the following type:

```
Either[Unit, Flow[String, T, Any]]
```

Can everyone tell me how to answer Unit in case the the out part of the flow is Left(RuntimeException) and T when it's right handed.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You need to also tell us what you have done so far, so I'm not going to write the code, but I'll give you some idea. Flow has no value inside itself (like a function, receives some input, produces some output, no value inside itself), it just describes some behavior. So you'll actually need a `Source` to apply this behavior to. having the source, you'll also need to store the output of the flow somewhere, so you'll also need a `Sink`. Having the sink and the source, you'll have access to `Either[RuntimeException, T]` this, and you can then apply pattern matching or something similar to it.

Comment: My case is a little more complicated cause I am in akka http wrapped within Tapir - it's a library that produce the documentation. Within Tapir I connect Endpoit and it's logic. And I am inside a function that collect the result from another function - the Flow[String, Either[RuntimeException, T], Any] - and I have to provide to Tapir a Either[Unit, Flow[String, T, Any]]. Sink and Source are not known where I am - I guess they are dealt latter in Tapir

Comment: What exactly is the desired behavior?  The question you're asking in general cannot be done, so it's likely that there's another way to get the behavior you want.  Specifically, the `Either[Unit, Flow[String, T, Any]]` is _only_ meaningful in the case where there's never a `Flow` (e.g. something in the process of setting up the websocket logic went wrong, not in response to data sent through the websocket).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that:

- Tapir expects that error to return to the user is `Either[Unit, Flow[String, T, Ant]]` (error algebra is not provided - `Unit` - so it expects that no error information will be returned to the user)
- OPs business logic provides `Flow` working with `Either[RuntimeException, T]`
- if there are some errors during websocket processing, their result can be stored in `T` (so `T` has to be internally something like Either or similar ADT)

So endpoint either never fails on connection, or on failure shows no information to the user (since Left T = Unit). Once connected it can just return errors as websocket responses in the form of `T`.

In such case whole flow could just be wrapped in `Right(flow)` and one obstacle is worked out.

Then `RuntimeException` can be converted to `T` and the second obstacle would be defeated.

```
def handleRequest(input: Input): Either[
  Unit, // Left(()) is failure but without any error information for users
  Flow[String, Either[RuntimeException, T], Any] // Right(flow) on success
] = ...

// implementation depends on T and is only possible if T can somehow store
// either success and failure result
val mapError: RuntimeException => T = ...

def tapirLogic(input: Input): Either[Unit, Flow[String, T, ]] = for {
  // if we should go Left on request handling this is the moment
  businessLogic <- handleRequest(input)
  // turns Either[RuntimeExeption, T] to T
  flow = businessLogic.map((_.fold(mapError, identity)))
} yield flow
```

What if `T` isn't able to store failures? What if it cannot be encoded e.g. as something like:

```
{ "success": "success response" }
{ "failure": "failure response" }
```

or similar?

In such case your API definition is not prepared for encoding error messages that you would have to sent to your users on `RuntimeException` result within your business logic definition. Maybe you don't want to send anything in such case - then you could use some `Flow` operator which e.g. `flatMapConcat` single value on Right and empty Flow on Left. But if you want to be able to return some message to the user, then Tapir has to know how to encode it, and so `T` has to somehow encode it. Maybe you need two different `T`s: encoding only success in original flow and encoding both `T` and `RuntimeException` messages in flow transformed for Tapir. Here types tell you what to do to make your implementation correct.